# 100 mg (of?) caffeine

Tags: prepositions

I'm aware that it is common to write:

> 8 oz of an energy drink can contain 100 mg **of** caffeine.

I'm also aware that "of" is often omitted in short texts, like in charts.

Anyway, is it plain wrong to write in an article:

> 8 oz of an energy drink can contain 150 mg caffeine.

?

Comment: Yes it is (wrong).

Comment: The _of_ would be omitted in scientific writing, but included in an article for the general reader.

Comment: It's a shorthand that comes from prescription / medical order doctors' shorthand.  I'm pretty sure almost all English readers would understand it and most would not give it a second thought or think it was awkward.   But it is probably better to include the preposition.

Comment: Interestingly, compare the idiomatic British use:  "five pounds sterling"...  also <measure quantifier> <material> with no "of" present.